# Resolving conflicts in PR

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi:

I recently submitted a PR. However, there were some failing tests which I have addressed. I also find that there is now a conflict with the lunar-devel branch. I'm not sure what is the best way to proceed from here? I can add more commits to the PR which will fix the failing tests, but I don't know how to fix the conflict in the PR. Do I rebase my branch to the head of the lunar-devel branch? or is there some other recommended way?

Also, it seems that the lunar-devel branch has some failed tests and therefore the PR also has some failed tests. How can I resolve this?

I'd appreciate any pointers to this.

[edit1]
In particular, I'm refering to the ros_comm package and the Secure ROS PR: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1080

Thanks,
Aravind.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268978/resolving-conflicts-in-pr/) by [Aravind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19767/aravind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
What package/repository are you referring to? Also, this may be better answered in the repository that you're try to do a pull request in.

**Comment by [Aravind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19767/aravind/) on 2017-08-16**:
Thanks for the response. I've updated my original question. When you say, answered in the original repository, do you mean a comment on the PR or something else?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
Yes, there or maybe an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though you refer to branches with ROS release names in them, this is essentially a non-ROS question. To really understand what is going on, I would suggest you take a look at a git / github tutorial or two.

As to your question:

> I can add more commits to the PR which will fix the failing tests, but I don't know how to fix the conflict in the PR. Do I rebase my branch to the head of the lunar-devel branch?

Rebasing is probably easiest, provided you have no history that you must preserve.

> Also, it seems that the lunar-devel branch has some failed tests and therefore the PR also has some failed tests. How can I resolve this?

That is obviously not something we can answer here, as, as @jayess already noted, we don't know which "pull request" and which particular "lunar-devel branch" you are referring to.

In general though, failures that are not caused by your PR are typically not considered as blockers for a merge.

But this can, and will, differ between repositories, as it's up to the maintainers.

You'll have to ask them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aravind](https://answers.ros.org/users/19767/aravind/) on 2017-08-16**:
I've updated my original post with the particulars. I meant it to be a more general question, and I think your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks!